# $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2...}}}$

I am trying to find the limit using the Monotone convergence theorem

But first I am trying to find an explicit presentation of $a_n$.

is the only presentation of it is a sequence $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^\frac{1}{2n}$$ ?

Comment: I think the third square root should cover all following radicals.

Comment: Also of many other posts, some with constant $c=2$, linked to that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

$$a_n:=\overbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\ldots+\sqrt2}}}^{n\;\text{times}}\implies \begin{cases}a_n\le a_{n+1}\\{}\\a_n\le 2\end{cases}\;\;\forall n$$

Prove then the limit *exists* and must be 2.

Comment: using induction I have proved that it is Monotone, but how can I prove that $a_n\leq 2$ by induction if I have not find $a_n$ explicitly?

Comment: Induction @gbox: $$a_1=\sqrt2\le 2\;,\;\;a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n}\le \sqrt{2+2}=\;etc.$$

Comment: = etc. means by the induction assumption $a_n\leq 2$ therefore $\forall_{n\in \mathbb{N}}a_n\leq 2$?

Comment: @gbox In fact, that "etc." means that $\;\sqrt{2+2}=2\;$ ... :) But yes, also that $\;a_n\le 2\;$ by the Ind. Assumption.

Answer (score 4):

$A=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2...}}}$

$A^2=2+A$

Comment: The second equality is true **if** you can first prove the expression for $\;A\;$ exists (finitely).

Answer (score 1):

$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+a_n}$ and $a_0 = 2$. The limit $l$ must by continuity satisfy $l = \sqrt{l+2}$. Therefore $l^2 = l +2$. So the limit is the positive root of $X^2 - X - 2$. (Note that the two root have opposite sign, as their product is $-2$.) I leave you finish. ;-)

Comment: As Timbuc already said below, for that to be true, it needs to be shown that $a_n$ converges.

Comment: @Robert Beside the fact that it must be proven (by you or, better, by the OP) that the limit exists, whose continuity are you referring to in your first line?

Comment: "I'm trying to find the limit" makes me assume that the OP knows the limit exists. And it's the continuity of the dimension of the fibers I'm referring to, as well as to the continuity of $x\mapsto\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ on its definition domain.

Comment: What? What fibers (of what) and what $\;\sin\frac1x\;$ are you talking about? Perhaps you did comment on the wrong question?!

Comment: No, I'm just nicely making fun of you. Because I guess that the OP got that it was continuity of $x\mapsto \sqrt{x+2}$ I was writing about.

Comment: Oh. That was hilarious (?)

Comment: It really was. Especially because I'm sure you know that there's no continuity of the fibers, but only upper continuity. This is the semicontinuity theorem. Valid as you know of course for proper morphisms of noetherian schemes and for coherent and flat sheaves on the base. I'm laughing again. Thanks so mmuch !